# Show Limited text/words in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#

I would like to show limited words in bootstrap card component, however it does not trim/truncate the words at appropriate position using `Substring()` in C#.

Here is my code:

```
LimitedWord = _postRepo.GetNumberOfWord(posts.Description, 200, "")
```

Implementation of logic in repository

```
public string GetNumberOfWord(string description, int length, string delimiter)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(delimiter))
    {
        return description.Substring(0, length);
    }
    else
    {
        return description.Substring(0, description.LastIndexOf(delimiter));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think such a method belongs to the repository at all. You can even try to achieve the same results using CSS (since you already mentioned Bootstrap).

Comment: What is "appropriate position"?

Comment: Do you know that string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace method will evaluate "" as true ? therefore the else block will not execute so you just get substring of description

Comment: What behaviour would you like to acomplish, because I am not even sure what this method is suposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

Just use Css

```css
div {
  padding: 15px;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.post-title {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-title">
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

Comment: this is simple and awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first `n` words of `description` using something like:

```
string.Join(" ", description.Split().Take(n))
```

How long do you expect `description` to be? If the string could get really long, it might sense to have an additional database column with a short description in it.

Answer (score 0):

None of above steps have resolved the problem, but i have changed the logic in the repository and this seems doing exactly what i wanted, by the way Thanks for your help:-

```
 public string GetNumberOfWord(string description, int length)
    {
        var biggestWord = 50;
        var elipse = "[...]";

        if (description == "undefined")
        {
            return description;
        }
        var truncatedText = description.Substring(0, length + biggestWord);
        while(truncatedText.Length > length - elipse.Length)
        {
            var lastSpace = truncatedText.LastIndexOf(" ");
            if(lastSpace == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            truncatedText = truncatedText.Substring(0, lastSpace).Replace("/[!,.?]$/","");
        }
        return truncatedText + elipse;

    }
```